# How do I align these letters to the same baseline?

Tags: plane-geometry

Given the following letters, all are absolutely aligned vertically to the bottom, however I need to align them to their baseline.

[image]

How can that calculate the letter vertical offset?

- Each letter is currently displayed vertically with `y = bottomY - fontSize` (all in pixels)
- `fontSize` is proportional to `h` (i.e. `fontSize = h * 0.5` for `50%`)
- the descent value `d` is a variable obtained per font family, e.g. `d = h * 0.22`

I know that, for a scaling of `1` (`100%`), the offset should be `0`, and it seems like for `0.5` (`50%`), the offset seems to `offset = d / 2`, but what about when the scaling is `0.1` (`10%`)?

Thank you for helping me understand the math behind this.

Comment: What does this have to do with the tag linear-programming?

Comment: I don't know. I had to add a tag, and did not know what to put. I'm a programmer, and when I ask on SO, I know what tag goes there but I'm not a mathematician.

Comment: If you read the tag description, you'll see that linear programming has a very specific meaning which is completely different from your problem here. That said, it's not so easy to say what topic your question belongs to. I'll change it to plane-geometry, and we'll see if anyone else comes up with something better.

Comment: I've been on StackOverflow for over 11 years, and your comment is why I'm always relunctant to come here; either change the tags if you find it innapopriate, or answer the question. All this is irrelevant, and does not help anything.